# Pass a variable to an Assetic asset URL in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

Is there a way to pass a variable to the Assetic method in templates

```
{% stylesheets
    '@SomeExampleBundle/Resources/views/ SOMEVAR /css/*'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

So what I want to do is pass `SOMEVAR` from the controller.

Comment: Use PHP as template language and just script it. Otherwise implement the logic in PHP and inject that into the twig language.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For now, I don't think it is possible at all. The reason behind this is that `Assetic` is run upfront to dump the assets, so it does not run the Twig template to compute the variable. This is probably the same if you do it in a PHP template.

This means that runtime variables will not be computed and expanded. Thus, this make it impossible to generate the assets if a variable is used. This may change in the future, but this would incur an overhead in production each time the assets are requested by the user because `Assetic` would need to generate the assets.

I know it is possible to programmatically defines and generates the asset by using the code found in `Assetic` directly (not by using the `AsseticBundle`). You will need to experiment, read the source code, and do trials and errors to work out off this problem.

There is little to no documentation on `Assetic` at the moment. The only link I can give is the `README` found on the github page of Assetic [here](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/README.md). I hope this will change soon.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 25):

It is possible through this way :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/yourbundle/css/'~ SOMEVAR ~'/css/' ) }}" />
```

Comment: this doesn't use `assetic`, but symfony's `asset` function. you can not use filters with this

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate a bit on Chopchop's answer:

First you need to include all files that assetic needs to dump, as it needs to know what you need dumped. What you can make in a conditional manner is the inclusion of the asset itself at runtime.

So first put in the assetic part:

```
{% javascripts 
'@ExampleComBundle/Resources/public/js/module1.js'
'@ExampleComBundle/Resources/public/js/module2.js'
%}
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Now you can put in the condition that you wanted. Both those script will be dumped at deployment time but you will be able to choose at runtime which one to include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/examplecombundle/js/module' ~ WHICH_MODULE_TO_INCLUDE ~ '.js ) }}" />
```

The ~ character is just the concatenation operator in Twig templates.

Works of course the same with CSS and JS.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, which works with limited ranges of options (Piotr's solution didn't work for me in dev mode):

```
{% javascripts
    '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/module_A.js'
    output='js/module_A.js'
%}
    {% if myVar == "A" %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endif %}
{% endjavascripts %}

{% javascripts
    '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/submodule1_B.js'
    '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/submodule2_B.js'
    '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/submodule3_B.js'
    output='js/module_B.js'
%}
    {% if myVar == "B" %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endif %}
{% endjavascripts %}

...
```

That way, each module will be dumped on deployment or dynamically handled by assetic, AND you can choose which module to be included, using **myVar**.

Note: I used the javascripts block here, but it will work the same with stylesheets.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I didn't understand, but... are you trying to do this?

```
{% stylesheets
    '@SomeExampleBundle/Resources/views/' ~ somevar ~ '/css/*'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Because, as far as I know, the string passed to `stylesheets` is  a valid Twig expression, so you're free to use variable interpolation.

Anyway, I don't think it's a good practice to have dynamic assets. What do you exactly want to achieve? There may be a better solution.