# Is it possible to create a conditional path to an asset using assetic and twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

Basically, I want to know if something like the following is possible:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/acme/images' {% if something is defined %}'-blah{{ someId }}'{% endif %} '.png') }}" />
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8286470/399584) the answer is likely no, but I want to make sure.

Comment: edit: The code snippet was outright unreadable in the comment, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you put the if outside the `asset`-call like this:

```
<img src="
{%- if something is defined -%}
    {{ asset('bundles/acme/images-blah' ~ someId ~ '.png') }}
{%- else -%}
    {{ asset('bundles/acme/images-blah.png') }}
{%- endif -%}
" />
```