# Symfony2 Javascript Assets - variables as arguments

Tags: symfony, twig, assets

Suppose i have following code in my view:

```
{% set foo = '@CmsFooBundle/Resources/public/js/scripts.js' %}

{% javascripts filter="yui_js"
    '@CmsBarBundle/Resources/public/js/other_scripts.js'
     %}
     <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Question: how to pass "foo" variable as an argument into "javascripts" block?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a variable to an Assetic asset URL in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285562/pass-a-variable-to-an-assetic-asset-url-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Pass a variable to an Assetic asset URL in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285562/pass-a-variable-to-an-assetic-asset-url-in-symfony2) is a link to this blog article http://jmsyst.com/blog/asset-variables-in-assetic

it shows you how to do it, although you need to have a finite number of variables and Assetic 1.1+

Comment: The URL you included doesn't work anymore. Could you please provide another one @stefancarlton ?