# Tenant-specific CSS file in Twig master template

Tags: php, css, symfony, assetic

We have a symfony 2.4 app that is a multi-tenant one. That means we share the same codebase between a few organizations, separating the access by domain name. So it looks like:

- organization1.domain.com
- organization2.domain.com
- organization3.domain.com

We also use [Assetic bundle](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) to process our .scss and .css files that are common (as of today) for all organizations. So basically all the tenants have the same design. The master layout looks like:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
    '@MainBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap-2.3.1.css'
    '@MainBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap-responsive-2.3.1.css'
    '@MainBundle/Resources/public/sass/main.scss'
%}
```

where in `main.scss` we define all our SCSS rules for all organizations.

Now one of the organizations asks for a design change that probably the others don't want to have. I would like to place the organization-specific .css'es or .scss'es into a folder and add another `stylesheets` loop in my master layout. The problem is in the assetic not willing to respect the Twig variables when processing the resources. Let me explain by an example and a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285562/pass-a-variable-to-an-assetic-asset-url-in-symfony2) , if I do something similar to:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
'@MainBundle/Resources/public/sass_organizations/*.css'
%}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

after the main `stylesheets` loop I mentioned above, it will process **ALL** the resources in `Resources/public/sass_organizations` no matter what organization they correspond to. So I need a kind of condition in the Twig template basing on the current domain name. In other words, something like

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
'@MainBundle/Resources/public/sass_organizations/' ~ organization.id  ~ '.css'
%}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

and if I do something like latter, assetic bundle will crash with `Unexpected token \"operator\" of value \"~\" in ...`  exception - yes, as it doesn't know anything about Twig and its engine when processing the resources.

**TL;DR**: need to serve css files through assetic bundle, but not all in a folder, but basing on a condition in a Twig template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project I use some kind like this solution:
https://developer.happyr.com/rename-dump-from-asseticbundle

We add git_commit part to output css/js name, because Amazon S3 ignores "cache busters" like filename.css?cachebuster=jhjgfsjdfg

Instead of git_commit You can pass there whatever You want since You have access to container :)

Comment: Thanks a LOT, @barat! It works and the only thing I needed to do was creating {organization}.css file in the directory where I store overridden .css. Like the other one mentioned in this comment: https://github.com/symfony/assetic-bundle/issues/136#issuecomment-109425518  , otherwise it just fails with an exception "Unable to find file "...../{organization}.css"